# Invalid checkout path when running shell script on dos prompt with cygwin installed

Tags: svn, path, cygwin

This is the checkout location when invoking a shell script on dos prompt

```
+ svn co svn+ssh://builder@dev.serv/svn/scripts/Core_V6 /cygdrive/c/.jenkins/jobs/TEST_BUILD/workspace/
A    C:\cygdrive\c\.jenkins\jobs\TEST_BUILD\workspace\test.sh
```

the path here is invalid (Expecting: C:.jenkins\jobs\TEST_BUILD\workspace\test.sh), an additional cygdrive folder gets created in c:\ and it is not referring to cygdrive folder in cygwin installation.

when running the checkout from the cygwin terminal it gives a valid path

```
$ svn co svn+ssh://builder@dev.serv/svn/scripts/Core_V6 /cygdrive/c/.jenkins/jobs/TEST_BUILD/workspace/
A    /cygdrive/c/.jenkins/jobs/EVEREST_BUILD/workspace/Everestv6builder/everest_orj.sh
```

this does not create any additional folders. cygwin version 1.7.17 is the one that is used.

what possibly could be the reason for the path to be misinterpreted when a sub-process is forked ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I was using a text editor where the EOL ( CRLF ) was set to DOS/Windows. When using cygwin, the EOL should be converted to UNIX EOL ( LF ).